# Why won't this UIToolBar appear?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitoolbar

Here is the init method of the root view controller of my navigation controller that I am trying to display the toolbar on:

```
-(id) initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    if(self){
        //GUI implementation
        self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO;
        UIBarButtonItem *flexiableItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                                                                                       target:self
                                                                                       action:nil];
        UIBarButtonItem *item1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh
                                                                               target:self
                                                                               action:nil];
        self.toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:flexiableItem, item1, nil];

        UIBarButtonItem* addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd
                                                                                   target:self
                                                                                   action:@selector(addEmployee)];

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
    }
    return self;
}
```

and here is my delegate `application:DidFinishLaunching` method in the app delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    BOHomeViewController* hvc = [[BOHomeViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];

    UINavigationController* navbar = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:hvc];
    [self.window setRootViewController:navbar]; 

    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

The toolbar is not showing up at all. Could someone point out where I am doing something wrong? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the initializing of your toolbarItems to the initializer you're actually calling ( `initWithTableViewStyle:` ) and `self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO;` to viewWillAppear as `self.navigationController` will be nil in your intializer.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not calling it!

You are calling

```
BOHomeViewController* hvc = [[BOHomeViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
```

where you should be calling

```
BOHomeViewController* hvc = [[BOHomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:<"Some Name"> bundle:<"Some Bundle">];
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, `initWithNibName` is no called. Yoc call `initWithStlye`.

And even then - at that point in time your hvc is not part of a navigation hierarchy. Meaning self.navigationController should be nil during init. It gets value as soon as it is assigned as rootviewcontroller to the later newly created `UINavigationController`.